# How do I use parameterized interfaces?

Tags: system-verilog

I am struggling to understand interfaces.  At first, they seem simple enough, but once I started to work with parameterized interfaces, I just can't get the pieces to fall into place.

I have this interface:

```
interface my_if #( 
    parameter H_WIDTH = 64,
    parameter L_WIDTH = 8
);
logic [H_WIDTH -1:0]  a;
logic [L_WIDTH -1:0]  b;
logic                 ready;
modport in ( input a, input b, output valid);
modport out( output a, output b, input ready);
endinterface;
```

and I want to use that as a port in my module:

```
module my_module (
logic input clk,
logic input rst,
my_if.in    my_if
);
```

I don't see how to set the parameters of my interface.
I have tried the following instead of the above:

```
my_if(#.H_WIDTH((64), .L_WIDTH(64)) my_if()
```

and

```
my_if(#.H_WIDTH((64), .L_WIDTH(64)).in my_if()
```

which does not compile.

How do I then set the parameters of my interface?

The solution has to synthesize as this is not for verification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set parameters of an `interface` instance exactly the same way you set parameters of `module`; when it is instantiated. There is no syntax that allows you to set the parameters of an interface port. The parameter values are based on the interface instance connected to the port when instantiating the module.

This presents a problem when the top level module you are synthesizing has an interface port. It similar to when the top-level module has parameters that needs to be overridden. You need to check the synthesis manual of the tool you are using to see how to manually override the parameters.

Answer (score 6):

You are almost there!  In your top module (where you instantiate the interface), you only have to change:

```
my_if(#.H_WIDTH((64), .L_WIDTH(64)) my_if()
```

to

```
my_if # (.H_WIDTH(64), .L_WIDTH(64)) my_if()
```

And you should be good to go.  The [IEEE 1800-2012 LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) has a section (25.8 Parameterized interfaces) on this topic that you should go over.

Comment: actually
module my_module (
logic input clk,
logic input rst,
my_if.in    my_if
);
was the correct solution

Answer (score 1):

Actually this was the correct way in the first place:

```
module my_module (
logic input clk,
logic input rst,
my_if.in    my_if
);
```

this:

```
module my_module (
logic input clk,
logic input rst,
my_if # (.H_WIDTH(64), .L_WIDTH(64)) my_if()
);
```

is apparently not legal.

The parameters are set where the interface is connected to another module!

`my_if # (.H_WIDTH(64), .L_WIDTH(64)) my_if_()` is used like so:

```
module top (
input clk,
input rst
);

my_if # (.H_WIDTH(64), .L_WIDTH(64)) temp_if();

my_module inst_1
 (
clk           (clk),
rst           (rst),
my_if         (temp_if)
);


my_module inst_2
 (
clk           (clk),
rst           (rst),
my_if         (temp_if)
);

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Synopsys DC flow it is recommended to create a simplified SystemVerilog wrapper to override interface and module paramters.

If you have access to Synopsys documentation see

HDL Compiler for SystemVerilog User Guide
Bottom-Up Hierarchical Elaboration